# XML Merge Optimization with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am hoping someone can point me in a right direction. I am writing a PHP app, which will basically pull about 10-15 xml feeds, with about 30 nodes in each of them with different formats, and then cluster them into various categories. So far I was able to write a piece of php to transform/map each feed via XSLT to a standardized format (xml elements are standardized across all output fields). I am able to do a simple include and include them all to output a single feed, problem comes that the feed is now about 400-500 nodes with 17 elements per node, and takes forever to load. That's where I'm stuck, I've tried XMLReader/XMLWriter command, but am getting an error on XML Writer. I am using the below code

```
$xml1 = new XMLReader();
$xml1->open('convert1.php');

$xml2 = new XMLReader();
$xml2->open('convert2.php');
    $name = 'xmlroot';

    $write = new XMLWriter();
    $write->startElement($name);
```

This is the error I get:

```
Warning: XMLWriter::startElement() [xmlwriter.startelement]: Invalid or unitialized XMLWriter object in C:\wamp\www\mergetest\merge1.php on line 22
```

My XML is structured like this:

```
<xmlroot>
<xmlnode>
<xmlelement></xmlelement>
</xmlnode>
</xmlroot>
```

Convert PHP code:

```
    <?php

$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load('xmlfeed');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('xsl.xsl');

$proc = new XSLTProcessor();
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);
```

I'm still new to PHP, so if there are noob mistakes or I didn't include something, please don't flame lol I'm just trying to learn, and any and all help are appreciated. I tried looking at the PHP reference/tutorial, but it doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alter your code thus

```
$write = new XMLWriter();
$write->openMemory();
$write->startElement($name);
...more code...
print $write->outputMemory();
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xmlwriter-write-element.php#87535